# Whats the windows equivalent of this simple bash string manipulation?

Tags: bash, scripting, batch-file

I'm once again, wishing I could use bash while trying to do some windows batch stuff.  What's a short, windows batch equivalent of this Bash expression?

```
$ var="EIPADDRESS=192.168.20.139"; IPAddress="${var##*=}" ; echo "IP: ${IPAddress}"
IP: 192.168.20.139
```

The above strips off everything up to and including the last instance of "=" in the string.

I've come up with something that strips of the first `n` characters, but I'd rather not rely on knowing the string form apriori:

```
set var="EIPADDRESS=192.168.20.139"
set IPAdress=%var:~11%
echo IP: %IPAddress%
```

Whatever solution is provided it must work with the vanilla install of Windows 7: so no third party tools please.

Comment: Don't give up so quickly, **Batch** is more powerful `:-)` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in PowerShell, which is installed on a vanilla Win7 install:

```
> $var = "EIPADDRESS=192.168.20.139"
> $var -match "(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}"
> $ip = $Matches[0]
```

That is how you would run it at the command prompt. Creating a `.ps1` file would be very similar to what is written here.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't familiar with "PowerShell" (which strikes me as a name with hubris).  Is it a simple matter to change the match scope from lengths to regular expressions (akin to `([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+`?

Comment: @Jamie - I am not sure what you are asking. The match pattern is a regular expression. [0-9] == \d (\d matches a digit). I made the required length to be between 1 and 3 since this is an IP address. It has to be at least 1 digit and can't be more than 3.  I did just notice a typo in my expression though. I intended the initial group to be `(\d{1,3}\.)`. I will fix that.

Comment: Oh.  Wasn't familiar with the `\d` syntax, which in hindsight is perfectly obvious.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this (yes, pure **Batch**):

```
(for %i in (EIPADDRESS=192.168.20.139) do @echo %i)|more +1
```

Comment: Wow.  Elegant.  Please pardon my surprise.  Is variable assignment just as plain?

Comment: @Endoro - very cool using EIPADDRESS=192.168.20.139 as a file name with the for stripping the = out then using more to only display the second "File"

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
$var = "EIPADDRESS=192.168.20.139"
$ipAddress = $var | select-string '(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d+' | foreach-object {
  $_.Matches[0].Groups[0].Value
}
"IP is $ipAddress"
```

Bill